# Ravendb - 'selecting' collection entities from parent entities

Tags: collections, indexing, ravendb

I am trying to create an index in raven that will (to all intents and purposes) project all comments on all blog-posts that were created by a specific user. At present I have managed a map statement, which only returns the posts that have comments.

```
    from post in docs.Posts
    from comment in Hierarchy(post, "Comments") 
    select new { comment.User, comment.Text }
```

At the end of this, I will want to page through the comments, so I need to get a flat list of all matching items.

Thanks

Comment: The problem I had was due to a lack of understanding with RavenDB.  I thought the map statement should just return the matching comment objects in an entity's graph.  In face, the a map statement is only used to select the documents to be returned.

It may be possible that the specific commend could be returned with a reduce statement, but I restructured my app a long while ago, so haven't really thought about it since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem that you have run to?
You are projecting the comment data out, you need to tell RavenDB to store the fields, but you can now query it just fine.

Comment: Ayende,The problem I have is that I do not want to comment out an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Comment>>.  I want to expose a flat list of comments that I can select from later.  To use the blog analogy, I want to show a page of a given user's comments, and haven't been able to create an index that would allow for this.